# How do I use multiple voices in a sequence with the `say` command?

Tags: macos, bash, text-to-speech

I am trying to use the `say` command on the mac terminal with **multiple voices in a sequence**.

For example, notice the following piece of code:

```
say -v 'Alex' 'Hello World'
say -v 'Kathy' 'Hello World!'
```

This would do what I want but it repeats the command `say`. What I pretend is something like this:

```
say -v 'Alex' 'Hello World' -v 'Kathy' 'Hello World'
```

*This line does not work but it represents what I'm trying to do.*

My **current script** is written as follows:

```
say -o ttsTest.aiff \
-v 'Kathy' "Hello world! This is Kathy speaking!" \
-v 'Fred' "And here is Fred." \
-v 'Bruce' "Right" \
-v 'Alex' "Alex over here, don't forget me."
```

The above code reads all the text in a single voice.

*References:*
[say(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/say.1.html)

*PS: As shown in the excerpt of my script above, I am trying to output the multiple voices into the same file.*

Comment: does `man say` give you any hope that it will accept multi-args as you would like? (I don't  have a Mac, I can't check). Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is not possible with the `say` command. If it was possible to do that, the references would surely note that `-v` can be used multiple times, which they don't.

What you will need is a tool to merge AIFF files. OS X doesn't come with one but such command line tools exist, e.g. [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/), [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/), etc. but you will have to build them yourself.

BTW to get the reference of a command in terminal, just use the `man` tool, e.g. `man say` shows the reference (scroll up/down with the arrow keys, spacebar scrolls down a whole page, `<` goes to the first line, `>` to the last one, exit with `q`; you can also search, e.g. type `/voice` and hit enter, it will search forward for voice, `n` for search again, `?voice` searches for voice but backwards, hit `h` for even more help)

Answer (score 0):

You can run additional commands by chaining  `cmd1 && cmd2`.  So you would put

`say -v 'Alex' 'Hello World' && say -v 'Kathy' 'Hello World!'`.

Comment: Yes but that would still represent calling the function twice, there would be two output files. I want to call `say` only *once* so that I can add the `-o filename.aiff` output flag.

Comment: Just nitpicking, but `x && y` means "Only run y if x was successful. In this case it works, as x was successful but if you want to chain two commands and run the second one regardless if the first one was successful, it would be `x ; y`. And you can also do that `x || y` that means only run y if x was NOT successful.

Answer (score 0):

You could just write up a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ ! -z "$1" ]; do
    voice="$1"
    shift
    say -v "$voice" "$1"
    shift
done
```

Save it to a file, run `chmod +x myscript` and then call it like this:

```
`./myscript Kathy "Hello world! This is Kathy speaking!" Fred "And here is Fred." Bruce "Right" Alex "Alex over here, don't forget me."`
```